Contravariance/covariance with pure linear algebra
I have been struggling to understand tensors. For context, I just finished Axler's Linear Algebra chapter about dual spaces. I would be happy to be corrected about my understanding.

I understand that tensors can always act as either multilinear maps or simply an element of a space. For a particular choice of bases for each of the vector space in its tensor product, we can represent it using a block of numbers, such as a column, matrix, etc.

I also understand that the transformation rule for tensors is purely about its coordinates. In other words, if we don't talk about coordinates, and only work with its abstract nature, we never need to talk about the transformation rule.

The transformation rule is simply a reaction to a change of basis, aiming to "objectively preserve" the structure/functionality of the tensor if we change the numbers used to describe our space. However, I can't grasp the meaning of this "objectivity". Do they mean that the sum $\sum x^i e_i$ is constant? Then that means the sum is an n-tuple of numbers from a field $F$ living in a vector space $V$. And it means that all the transformation game happens in this single space $V$.

If my point 3 is correct, and we are working in usual field $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, then the n-tuple is represented in the standard basis. Doesn't this contradict the fact the the vector is an "objective" entity, "independent" of the basis, since I am using the standard basis?

I am reading Porat's Gentle Introduction to Tensors. From what I understand, all the quantities $a, T, S$ are just representations in particular coordinates. These quantities can be mentally arranged in high-dimensional box-like fashion. I understand that a tensor has two types of coordinates that change in "opposite" fashion. The picture 1.28 shows the transformation rule for change of bases, where each $T$ before $a$ is the inverse transformation with respect to a particular basis transformation for the respective contravariant coordinate, and where each $S$ after $a$ is the direct transformation equal to the particular basis transformation for the respective covariant coordinate. (The indices designate the vector space that the transformation is respective to.)

Are there intuitive examples that illustrate a change of basis for a tensor of rank 3 or more, that are purely linear algebraic (no partial derivatives)? Or even just for a tensor of rank 2? I understand the examples for vectors and dual vectors, but I can't generalize them to think about matrices or higher.

What do we mean when we "consider contravariant/covariant coordinates"? Isn't it more appropriate to say contravariant and covariant indices?

Is Cartesian product of vector spaces simply the set of all possible tensor products of vectors in each space?

Why is it that, when given a basis change, the matrix of a linear transformation changes with $S^{-1} M S$? I've only specified a single basis change, but I use it for both the contravariant and covariant indices.


